# CTRL-R not working in Pycharm despite showing in Keymap

Tags: pycharm, keymaps

So I am using PyCharmCE and upon launching this morning, I cannot seem to get ctrl-r working to run the script in the editor.  All other keymaps seem to be working correctly, and ctrl-r appears in the Keymap setup area.  Also, the green triangle does not appear to executer the script either, so I think it is running upon ctrl-r or green triangle press command, but I no longer see any output window.

The script I am editing executes fine when I execute it from the terminal inside or outside PyCharm.

Any idea why it is only this ctrl-r that no longer works.  Typical - as it's one of the most frequently used shortcuts I use.